# PHP switch syntax

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I am a NOOB with PHP and trying to figure out the SWITCH syntax. 
I know how to do the case statement like the following:

```
$numbr = 2;
switch ($numbr) {
  case 2:
    echo "numbr is equal to 2";
    break;

   case 1:
     echo "numbr is 1";
     break;
}
```

but if I use this instead (checking for a number greater than 1) it breaks. What am I doing wrong?

```
$numbr = 2;
switch ($numbr) {
  case >1:
    echo "numbr is greater than 1";
    break;

  case 1:
  echo "numbr is 1";
    break;
}
```

Comment: I suppose `case >1:` is even a syntax error.

Comment: You can't do that with a switch. Each "case" is discrete, not relative like ">1". It seems like you want an if/else not a switch here.

Comment: this works - case $numbr >1:

Comment: Technically `case` can have a boolean condition like `case $numbr > 1` but that is very ugly and confusing. This would be better expressed as an `if/else if/else`

Comment: `case $numbr >1:` works but only in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statements are not good to use in these cases, instead, you should use [if/else](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

```
if($numbr > 1) {
    echo "numbr is greater than 1";
} else if($numbr == 1) {
    echo "numbr is 1";
}
```

Switches are most useful when comparing a value to many other values, not for comparing a value with a mathematical expression or logic.

It's better to use switches than if statements when possible, because switch statements are only evaluated once, whereas if statements are evaluated for every `if()`.

Comment: thanks. It seems the switch isn't meant for much "logic" whereas if/else does more testing?

Comment: @ScottPlude Exactly! You could also read up on the links I put in my answer. And be sure to check the checkmark next to the answer that helped you the most, as it will gain you and the answerer a little bit of reputation, and show future visitors the answer you chose as most helpful.

Comment: thank you! I truly appreciate your time and I promise I spent a little over an hour trying to figure it out before posting my question.

Comment: @ScottPlude No problem! Sometimes people lack the proper search terms to find answers to their questions, and just need a little push in the right direction. I'm glad that I could help you out with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put that as a case, there must be a value.

A good solution could be this one, but only for positive values:

```
$numbr = 2;
switch ($numbr) {
  case 0:
    break;

  case 1:
  echo "numbr is 1";
    break;

  default:
    echo "numbr is greater than 1";
    break;
}
```

If you want to handle also negative values you need to use if/else as others said

Comment: Note: If you supply this switch with a number _less than 0_, it will also echo "numbr is greater than 1". (Using a switch for this is really just not a good idea)

Comment: You're right, i just was trying to give him a solution manteining his choice, but if/else it's obviously better.

Comment: Edited a bit, just to indicate what you say :)